# Приложение на React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь написать приложение на реакте, оно должно работать следующим образом, пользователь вводит определенную сумму, сумма сравнивается с прайсом в базе данных, и если есть совпадение, то создается блок с картинкой машины, подходящей под определенную сумму. Проблема в том, что когда пользователь вводит сумму подходящую для самой дешевой машины, появляется и самая дорогая.

[image: БД]
[image: Код]

Comment: код лучше добавлять сниппетом, а не картинкой

Comment: потому что у вас условие `userMoney >= price`, то есть __больше или равно__

Comment: код работает как нужно, вы условие не правильно написали

Comment: и выводить весь массив через `map`, где будет только один норм элемент, а остальные `null` немного странно